# brew cask install android-sdk

Tags: android, homebrew, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I’m having problem to install android sdk (`brew cask install android-idk`) on Mac OS X.
I tried to install it for nativescript. I read on people that had the same problem but i couldn't find working solution. 
I tried to change the java path maybe it cause the issue.

this is the error I get:

```
==> Caveats
We will install android-sdk-tools, platform-tools, and build-tools for you.
You can control android sdk packages via the sdkmanager command.
You may want to add to your profile:
  'export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/local/share/android-sdk'

This operation may take up to 10 minutes depending on your internet connection.
Please, be patient.

==> Satisfying dependencies
==> Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-darwin-3859397.zip
Already downloaded: /Users/jhon/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Cask/android-sdk--3859397,26.0.1.zip
==> Verifying checksum for Cask android-sdk
==> Installing Cask android-sdk
==> Warning: Failed to download any source lists!
==> Warning: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/jhon/.android/cache/sdkbin-1_b735609c-repository2-1_xml
==> Warning: Failed to find package tools
Error: Command failed to execute!

==> Failed command:
/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/3859397,26.0.1/tools/bin/sdkmanager tools platform-tools build-tools;26.0.1

==> Standard Output of failed command:


==> Standard Error of failed command:
jhon-MacBook-Pro-8:appNativescript jhon$ brew cask install android-idk --verbose --debug
Error: Cask 'android-idk' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.
Error: Install incomplete.
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cli/install.rb:13:in `run'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cli/abstract_command.rb:35:in `run'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cli.rb:97:in `run_command'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cli.rb:167:in `run'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cli.rb:131:in `run'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/cask.rb:8:in `cask'
jhon-MacBook-Pro-8:appNativescript jhon$ brew cask install android-sdk
==> Caveats
We will install android-sdk-tools, platform-tools, and build-tools for you.
You can control android sdk packages via the sdkmanager command.
You may want to add to your profile:
  'export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/local/share/android-sdk'

This operation may take up to 10 minutes depending on your internet connection.
Please, be patient.

==> Satisfying dependencies
==> Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-darwin-3859397.zip
Already downloaded: /Users/jhon/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Cask/android-sdk--3859397,26.0.1.zip
==> Verifying checksum for Cask android-sdk
==> Installing Cask android-sdk
==> Warning: Failed to download any source lists!
==> Warning: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/jhon/.android/cache/sdkbin-1_b735609c-repository2-1_xml
==> Warning: Failed to find package tools
Error: Command failed to execute!

==> Failed command:
/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/3859397,26.0.1/tools/bin/sdkmanager tools platform-tools build-tools;26.0.1

==> Standard Output of failed command:


==> Standard Error of failed command:
Warning: Failed to download any source lists!
Warning: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/jhon/.android/cache/sdkbin-1_b735609c-repository2-1_xml
Warning: Failed to find package tools


==> Exit status of failed command:
#<Process::Status: pid 35477 exit 1>
Error: Install incomplete.
jhon-MacBook-Pro-8:appNatives
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is what docs say and you can give it a try -

**Solution 1 -**

*Install the dependencies for Android development.*

**Install JDK 8 or a later stable official release.**

- Go to Java SE Downloads and click Download for JDK.
- In the Java SE Development Kit section, accept the license agreement and click the download link for Mac macOS.
- Wait for the download to complete and install the JDK.
- Set the JAVA_HOME system environment variable.
- export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
  Install the Android SDK.

Run the following commands in the `Terminal`:

- `brew cask install android-sdk`

Next, run the following command to set the `ANDROID_HOME` system environment variable:

- `export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/share/android-sdk`

*NOTE: This is the directory that contains the tools and platform-tools directories.
In addition, install all packages for the Android SDK Platform 25, Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.2 or later, Android Support Repository, Google Repository and any other SDKs that you may need. You can alternatively use the following command, which will install all required packages.*

- `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager`

*"tools" "platform-tools" "platforms;android-25" "build-tools;25.0.2" "extras;android;m2repository" "extras;google;m2repository"
Setup Android Emulators (AVD) by following the article here*

**OR**

**Solution 2**

Download Android Studio and update for API levels and support repos that's it - Works all the time for me 
[Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)

Comment: How can I setup command line tools after downloading Android Studio?

Comment: need more info on that? Didn't get what ur saying?